# Compact generation of Voevodsky motives

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

Let $DM(k,{\mathbb{Q}})$ be the derived category of Voevodsky motives over a field $k$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients.

As a triangulated category is $DM(k,{\mathbb{Q}})$ known or expected to be compactly generated? What can be said about its set of compact objects if it is?